# Not able to read data to csv file using pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle, csv

I have a below data in table need to read entire data in table to **pandas** after performing cumulative sum and average need to generate csv file [ *comma separated file with headers* ]

```
NAME,AGE,MARKS
A1,12,40
B1,13,54
C1,15,67
D1,11,41
E1,16,59
F1,10,60
```

**I tried to write got stuck**

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

try : 
    sq='select * from emp'

    conn=cx_Oracle.cpnnect(myconnection)
    fd=pd.read_sql(sql,con=conn)
    fd['CUM_SUM'] = fd['MARKS'].cumsum()
    fd['AVG'] = fd['MARKS'].expanding().mean()
    fd.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

except Exception as er:

    print(er)
```

**Expected output in csv file with headers**

```
NAME,AGE,MARKS,CUM_SUM,AVG
A1,12,40,40,40
B1,13,54,94,47
C1,15,67,161,53.66
D1,11,41,202,50.5
E1,16,59,261,43.5
F1,10,60,321,45.85
```

When i do print(fd) , it gives below output

```
NAME ..CUM,AVG
A1,..,40,40
B1,..,94,47
C1,..,161,53.66
D1,..,202,50.5
E1,..,261,43.5
F1,..,321,45.85
```

Comment: Please, describe what exactly is wrong with your current code.

Comment: @astentx : Not able to read data to csv file

Comment: @astentx : Do i need to use cusor.fetchall to read entire data

Comment: You cannot read data to file. And what the "not able" means? Do you have any errors? Do you have an output that doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Get rid of that `try: except:`. You'll never see what the actual error and traceback are. Then, maybe `cpnnect` should be `connect`.

Comment: If you do 'print(df)' what do you get? and what does the csv file contain?

Comment: @astentx : This 3 is their in table  `NAME,AGE,MARKS` remaining CUM and AVG calculating using pandas this all column data of table and calulated cum and avg should be written to file

Comment: @astentx : just check question i have updated what i am getting and what i am expected as output

Comment: You need to debug your code and chech each step. Then identify the step at which the transormation you applied returns not what you expect. Then ask the question about **this exact** problem, describing your issue. It is not clear what is wrong with the code (except `cponnect` that may be lost when you've replaced your connection information)

Comment: The `...` indicates there are more columns in the DF that aren't getting printed. If you don't need every column from the SQL table, then `select name, age, marks from emp` instead of `select *`...

Comment: @astentx : I want all colum bro with that CUM and AVG calculated using pandas in csv file

Comment: And what is the content of the file after the code gets executed?

Comment: @astentx : I need the expected output shown in question

Comment: Just as a side observation, you should not store 'age' in your tables.  "Age" changes daily, so would require a daily job to recalculate the whole table.  Store the 'start date' (date_of_birth if your 'age' is the age of a human), then compute age as and when needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2

conn = 'postgresql+psycopg2://DB_USER:DB_PASS@DB_HOST:5432/DB_NAME'     # 5432 = DB_PORT

# Connect to DB
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn)
connect = engine.connect()
inspector = sqlalchemy.inspect(engine)
# inspector.get_table_names()

# Read data from table_name and add to data-frame
df = pd.read_sql("select * from table_name", connect)
# df.head(10)

# calculation

# Write to csv with headers and comma delimiter
df.to_csv('filename.csv', sep=',', header=True)
```

Docs for .to_csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: It works but how to calculate the cumulative sum and average of MARKS columns that also i want in csv file

Comment: You will need a group by for any aggregations like so `select sum from table_name group by columns`.